# Javadoc of ArrayUtils.isNotEmpty is faulty?

Tags: java, arrays, apache-commons-lang

The javadoc of `ArrayUtils.isNotEmpty()` in Apache Commons Lang seems to be wrong. Or, at least, misleading.  It says

> Returns:
>     true if the array is not empty or not null

In my understanding, an empty array is not `null`. So, according to the above definition, `isNotEmpty()` should return `true` for an empty array, which is counterintuitive.

Wouldn't

> Returns:
>     true if the array is not null and not empty

be more correct?

Comment: Are you going to say which `ArrayUtils` are you talking about? There is no such class in Java API.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say. It's `ArrayUtils` from [org.apache.commons.lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html), both version 2.6 and 3.2.1

Comment: Seems like it was an issue only until 3.4 Has been fixed since 3.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Wouldn't
>
> > Returns: true if the array is not null and not empty
>
> be more correct?

Yes you are right. The doc is a bit misleading. In fact, if you see the source code, it does exactly that:

```
public static boolean isNotEmpty(Object[] array) {
   return (array != null && array.length != 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> In my understanding, an empty array is not null.

Not correct. Counterexample:

```
int a[];
```

`a` is an *empty array* (as it doesn't contain anything), and it's also `null` since it wasn't initialized.

In this case, `isNotEmpty` will return `false`, since **it is** empty.

Comment: Sorry but I've to completely disagree with your *empty array* point. `int[] a` is not an empty array, because there is no array at all.

Comment: @RohitJain If you pass `a` to a method that expects an array, it'll be fine.. So what is `a`? Just a reference?

Comment: Yeah, but that reference should point to an array, which should not be empty. Now, as it is pointing to a non-empty array, it cannot be `null`. Frankly speaking, OP is right. The doc comment is wrong, and not consistent with the code. See my answer.

Comment: @RohitJain Thanks for your remark, I'll further investigate this.

Comment: @RohitJain So in words, if I write `int a[];`, what you say `a` is? How is it differ from `String b;`? (Both are not initialized)

Comment: Yeah, both are references initialized to `null` by default.

Comment: @RohitJain No `int a[];` and `String b;` are not initialized to `null`. Simply aren´t  initialized, if you try to use them you will get a compiler error 'The local variable a may not have been initialized'